# PHP to extract a word before the open parenthesis

Tags: php, regex

I have a strings like,

> Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830 (Onyx Black)
>   Samsung Galaxy Y Color Plus S5360 (Metallic Grey)
>   HTC Radar (White Silver)
>   Micromax X560

how can i extract the particular string like

> Ace s5830
>   Y color Plus s5360
>   Radar
>   X560

from the string.

Comment: Have you got either a complete list of the input strings, or a complete list of the desired output strings? Also when you say the "particular string", what particular string are you talking about, exactly? There's no clear pattern to the examples you gave...

Comment: It looks like you want the model name, by removing the manufacturer's name and the color in the parens. This isn't possible automatically, you'll need a list of the manufacturers and the color will always need to be in parentheses.

Comment: Why would you remove `Galaxy` but not `Radar`?

Comment: Do you have the list of manufacturers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to have the list of manufacturers, but if you do then you can do something like this:

```
$MANUFACTURERS = array(
        "Samsung",
        "HTC",
        "Micromax"
    );
$descriptions = array(
        "Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830 (Onyx Black)",
        "Samsung Galaxy Y Color Plus S5360 (Metallic Grey)",
        "HTC Radar (White Silver)",
        "Micromax X560"
    );

$models = preg_replace(
    array_map(function($manufacturer) { 
        // Build a regex for each manufacturer
        return '/^'. preg_quote($manufacturer) .'\\s*|\\s*\\(.*\\)$/';
    }, $MANUFACTURERS), 
    '', // Replace manufacturer and color with an empty string
    $descriptions
);
```

Output (`$models`): `["Galaxy Ace S5830","Galaxy Y Color Plus S5360","Radar","X560"]`

Answer (score 1):

Use split().

First **split using '('** & then **split using ' ' (space)** & pick the **last element** of the array.

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

You can get strings like

```
Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830
HTC Radar
```

with a simple:

```
$paren_position = strpos($input, '(');
if ($paren_position !== false) {
   $output = substr($input, 0, $paren_position);
} else {
   $output = $input;
}
```

, but without a list of all possible manufacturers, you could never automatically remove the manufacturer name from the string. There is no way to automatically figure out where the manufacturer ends and the model begins.

Answer (score 1):

This requires a list of prefix-strings you want to not remove, unless your example was wrong and `"Galaxy Ace S5830"` is an acceptable output. In that case:

```
$bits = explode('(', $string);
$bits = explode(' ', $bits[0]);
array_shift($bits);
$out = trim(implode(' ', $bits));
```

This splits on `(`, taking everything before the first opening paren. It then splits on space, removing the first word in the string before joining the rest of the string back together.

Example code and output: http://codepad.org/Uxni2Xbr

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

```
$str = "Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830 (Onyx Black)";

$res = preg_split("/\s*\(/",$str);
$res = $res[0];
```

You will now get the string: `Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830` in `$res`

Answer (score 1):

use the preg_match function:

```
preg_match('/([^(]+)/', "Samsung Galaxy Ace S5830 (Onyx Black)", $matches);
```

see http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php